# --prof in node v4.x?

Tags: javascript, node.js, profiling, v8

I'm unable to get any profiling output from node 4.1.1:

```
[/tmp]% cat index.js                                                 (arkadiy@helium:/tmp)
console.log("boom");
[/tmp]% node --prof index.js                                         (arkadiy@helium:/tmp)
boom
[/tmp]% ls v8.log                                                    (arkadiy@helium:/tmp)
ls: v8.log: No such file or directory
[/tmp]% node --version                                               (arkadiy@helium:/tmp)
v4.1.1
[/tmp]% which node                                                   (arkadiy@helium:/tmp)
/usr/local/bin/node
```

`--prof` still appears to be a valid option and the manpage and all docs I can find seem to imply that the above invocation should generate a v8.log file I can analyze with e.g. `node-tick`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I can get a log with `--perf_basic_prof`

```
[/tmp]% node  --perf_basic_prof index.js                             (arkadiy@helium:/tmp)
boom
[/tmp]% ls *v8.log                                                   (arkadiy@helium:/tmp)
isolate-0x101804c00-v8.log
```